# jquery each within an each?

Tags: jquery, arrays

EDITED, this solves the question

To use the array like I've we need to loop 3 times like this code, thanks Alexander

```
var str = '';
    $.each(cores, function(i, value) {
        $.each(value, function(j, value_2) {
            $.each(value_2, function(k, sel_cor) {
                console.log(sel_cor);
                str += "<div class='cores' title="+sel_cor+" style='background-color:#"+sel_cor+"'></div>";
            });
        });
    });
```

I'm trying to make a jQuery colorpicker.

I've 3 arrays with hex colors, and I want to build litle squares for each one, so I need to each array each child of array.

Is this possible? How can this be done?

```
cores[0] = [["e3e3e7","e5e5e6","ecdfec","e6dfec","dfdfe6","dfe6e6","dfe6df","e8e8e0","f9f2df","f4e9df","ecdfdf","e5e4e2"]];
cores[1] = [["e3e3e7","e5e5e6","ecdfec","e6dfec","dfdfe6","dfe6e6","dfe6df","e8e8e0","f9f2df","f4e9df","ecdfdf","e5e4e2"]];
cores[2] = [["e3e3e7","e5e5e6","ecdfec","e6dfec","dfdfe6","dfe6e6","dfe6df","e8e8e0","f9f2df","f4e9df","ecdfdf","e5e4e2"]];

$.each(cores, function(j, value) {
            console.log('j = '+j+' value = '+value);
            str_claras += "<div class='tile' style='width:20px; height:20px; padding:0;margin:0;border:1px solid #333333;cursor:pointer;background-color:#"+j[value]+"'></div>";
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use javascript's built in for loop constructs?

```
for(core in cores)
{
   for(blah in blahs)
   {
      //...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $.each(cores, function(j, value) {

          $.each(value, function(i, value2) {

                str_claras += "<div class='tile' style='width:20px; height:20px; padding:0;margin:0;border:1px solid #333333;cursor:pointer;background-color:#"+value2+"'></div>";
        });
 });
```

here is the link: [***Click Here***](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/wWcYr/)

Comment: thanks Alexander, not yet, we still got all values from array ababb7,b0b1b4,c69fc6 and so on :-(

Comment: but mine array is not like the one you put there, its like cores[0] = [["e3e3e7","e5e5e6","ecdfec","e6dfec","dfdfe6","dfe6e6","dfe6df","e8e8e0","f9f2df","f4e9df","ecdfdf","e5e4e2"]];    Note that is is an array within another one to make it possible to separate color for density :-)    Thanks!